# Jquery remove element from var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with a parent div and several child divs. These are generated dynamically. I need to save the structure (html code) of all the child divs in my database, so I get the html content using .html().

But before I save the content in db, I need to remove one or more child divs. (But these divs will still need to be on the browser page)

How do I use the remove method with the selector (in this example I need to remove child3) on the output of .html()

```
<div id="graph-parent"> 
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
    <div id="child3"></div>
    <div id="child4"></div>
    <div id="child5"></div>
</div>


var htmlContent = $( "#graph-parent" ).html();
```

how do I remove child3 from htmlContent?

Comment: Sure seems like there must be a better way to accomplish whatever you're doing without saving an entire HTML structure to a database. Can't you just save the important parts? Or do you actually need a full snapshot?

Comment: ...anyway, to do what you want, `.clone()` the parent, traverse to the one you don't want and remove it, then save the `.html()` of the parent.

Comment: ...and to be clear, you don't do HTML string manipulation to add/remove elements. You treat the DOM like a DOM and remove nodes before serializing it to HTML.

Comment: Or you could just exclude the element from the collection with something like `not()`

Comment: @adeneo: It would still show up when getting the HTML though, wouldn't it?

Comment: Not if it's excluded from the collection, but that would require selecting the children and then excluding a certain child, and to get the same result one would then have to get the outerHTML, the question is why the heck the entire HTML is gotten at all, saving the HTML directly in a DB is like giving out an invintation to hackers to take over the site.

Comment: @adeneo: Yes, it would work with native `.outerHMTL` in supported browsers (which is most at this point). Would need to use `.each()` (or some iteration) and perhaps get `.contents()` if there may be text nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply clone the element and operate on that:

```
var clone = $('#graph-parent').clone();
clone.find('#child3').remove();
var htmlContent = clone.html();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/glegan/65QPV/

```
var clone = $('#graph-parent').clone();
clone.find('#child1').remove();
clone.find('#child5').remove();
var htmlContent = clone.html();
alert(htmlContent);
```